# I want my table at the bottom of the page to appear only at the bottom of the second tab

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a complete newbie to js, css, and html.  I am trying to make a website and I have come across a few problems.  I want to make my table which appears at the bottom of my page to appear only at the bottom of the second tab.  The problem right now is that the table appears at the bottom of every tab.  If someone could help me with this that would be great.  The code is below:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Apricot Consulting Group</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="apricot.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var tabLinks = new Array();
    var contentDivs = new Array();

    function init() {

      // Grab the tab links and content divs from the page
      var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
      for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
        if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
          var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
          var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
          tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
          contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
        }
      }
      // Assign onclick events to the tab links, and
      // highlight the first tab
      var i = 0;

      for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
        tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
        tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
        if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
        i++;
      }

      // Hide all content divs except the first
      var i = 0;

      for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        i++;
      }
    }

    function showTab() {
      var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

      // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
      // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
      for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( id == selectedId ) {
          tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
        } else {
          tabLinks[id].className = '';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        }
      }

      // Stop the browser following the link
      return false;
    }

    function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
        if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) return element.childNodes[i];
      }
    }

    function getHash( url ) {
      var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
      return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
    }


</script>
  </head>

<body onload="init()">

            <p> <img src="apricot.jpg" width="312" height="93" class="center"/> </p>

<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#resources">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#computers">Computers</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tabContent" id="aboutus">

<h1>About Us</h1>
    <div>
    <p>Apricot  Recruitment is a privately owned recruitment consultancy that
has been providing effective business solutions to organisations
throughout the UK.  At Apricot Recruitment we help find rewarding
temporary and permanent jobs for the job seeker, as well as provide
companies with highly skilled and motivated staff.  Our specially
trained consultants will find high quality candidates that match your
specific requirements. Clients and Candidates alike appreciate the
personal service we offer. Independent status means we always work in
the best interest of our customers and are therefore able to offer
complete flexibility of service. Each assignment is treated
individually in order to match both the client and candidates
requirements.</p>



</div>



</div>



<div class="tabContent" id="services">


<h1>Services</h1>

<div>

<p>Successful companies are built by successful people. Your company
needs the most talented, ambitious and determined individuals in order
to thrive. However, tracking down the ideal candidate can be
challenging.  We at Apricot Recruitment help you find that ideal
candidate.</p>

<p>By using our services you are able to outsource all your recruitment
needs to a single recruitment partner who oversees the entire supply
chain.  With an in depth knowledge of London Business, Apricot
Recruitment is ideally placed to help you locate and attract the best
possible candidates for your business. We specialise in going the
extra mile to find exactly the candidate to suit your business. Using
industry contacts and numerous research methods, we know precisely
where to look for your desired person.</p>

<p>The first step in recruiting the right candidates for your company is
learning about your business requirements, we thoroughly question,
evaluate and pre-interview all candidates before recommending only the
most appropriate for interview. This ensures you receive the very best
person for your role.</p>

<p>The Apricot Recruitment team uses a range of tools to source the best
possible talent.  These tools include:</p>



<ul>
<li>Extensive online and internal database searching.</li>
<li>Advertising in Premium Mediums.</li>
<li>Skills Assessment.</li>
<li>Headhunting.</li>
<li>Reference Checking.</li>
</ul>


</div>
</div>


<div class="tabContent" id="resources">

<h1>Resources</h1>

<div>

<p>We use lots of resources like monster, totaljobs, gumtree, etc.</p>


</div>
</div>



<div class="tabContent" id="computers">

<h1>Computers</h1>

    <p>Lots of computers.</p>
    <div>

<div id="DivPhotoGalleryFX"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var flashvars = {};
 var params = {};
 params.base = "";
 params.scale = "noscale";
 params.salign = "tl";
 params.wmode = "transparent";
 params.allowFullScreen = "true";
 params.allowScriptAccess = "always";
 swfobject.embedSWF("PhotoGalleryFX.swf", "DivPhotoGalleryFX", "935", "300", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params);


</script>


</div>


</div>




</body>

<div id="table">

<center>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>

</div>

<script>

tabLinks[services].onclick = display: block;

</script>

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}


h1 {
    font-family: times new roman;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

p {

    font-family: times new roman;
    color: black;
}

ul {
    font-family: times new roman;
    color: black;
}


img.center {

display: block;
margin-left: auto;  
margin-right: auto; 

}

 body { font-size: 90%; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; }
      ul#tabs { list-style-type: none; margin: 30px 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0.5em 0; }
      ul#tabs li { display: inline; }
      ul#tabs li a { color: black; background-color: goldenrod; border: 1px solid #c9c3ba; border-bottom: none; padding: 0.3em; text-decoration: none; }
      div.tabContent { border: 30px solid #c9c3ba; padding: 0.5em; background-color: goldenrod; }
      div.tabContent.hide { display: none; }
    div.table {display:none;}
```

Comment: do you mean the table should appear when services is clicked

Comment: mention the problem clearly

Comment: why is the table outside of the `<body>` tag?

Comment: Yes the table should appear when services is clicked.  But only at the bottom of the services tab outside of the thick silver border.  That is the reason I have the table outside the body tag.  Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. There seems to be other errors in your code but the table just needs to be moved in your markup:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Apricot Consulting Group</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="apricot.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tabLinks = new Array();
    var contentDivs = new Array();

    function init() {

      // Grab the tab links and content divs from the page
      var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
      for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
        if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
          var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
          var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
          tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
          contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
        }
      }
      // Assign onclick events to the tab links, and
      // highlight the first tab
      var i = 0;

      for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
        tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
        tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
        if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
        i++;
      }

      // Hide all content divs except the first
      var i = 0;

      for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        i++;
      }
    }

    function showTab() {
      var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

      // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
      // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
      for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( id == selectedId ) {
          tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
        } else {
          tabLinks[id].className = '';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        }
      }

      // Stop the browser following the link
      return false;
    }

    function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
        if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) return element.childNodes[i];
      }
    }

    function getHash( url ) {
      var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
      return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
    }


</script>
```

```
    <body onload="init()">

                <p> <img src="apricot.jpg" width="312" height="93" class="center"/> </p>

    <ul id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#resources">Resources</a></li>
        <li><a href="#computers">Computers</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tabContent" id="aboutus">

    <h1>About Us</h1>
        <div>
        <p>Apricot  Recruitment is a privately owned recruitment consultancy that
    has been providing effective business solutions to organisations
    throughout the UK.  At Apricot Recruitment we help find rewarding
    temporary and permanent jobs for the job seeker, as well as provide
    companies with highly skilled and motivated staff.  Our specially
    trained consultants will find high quality candidates that match your
    specific requirements. Clients and Candidates alike appreciate the
    personal service we offer. Independent status means we always work in
    the best interest of our customers and are therefore able to offer
    complete flexibility of service. Each assignment is treated
    individually in order to match both the client and candidates
    requirements.</p>



    </div>



    </div>



    <div class="tabContent" id="services">


    <h1>Services</h1>

    <div>

    <p>Successful companies are built by successful people. Your company
    needs the most talented, ambitious and determined individuals in order
    to thrive. However, tracking down the ideal candidate can be
    challenging.  We at Apricot Recruitment help you find that ideal
    candidate.</p>

    <p>By using our services you are able to outsource all your recruitment
    needs to a single recruitment partner who oversees the entire supply
    chain.  With an in depth knowledge of London Business, Apricot
    Recruitment is ideally placed to help you locate and attract the best
    possible candidates for your business. We specialise in going the
    extra mile to find exactly the candidate to suit your business. Using
    industry contacts and numerous research methods, we know precisely
    where to look for your desired person.</p>

    <p>The first step in recruiting the right candidates for your company is
    learning about your business requirements, we thoroughly question,
    evaluate and pre-interview all candidates before recommending only the
    most appropriate for interview. This ensures you receive the very best
    person for your role.</p>

    <p>The Apricot Recruitment team uses a range of tools to source the best
    possible talent.  These tools include:</p>



    <ul>
    <li>Extensive online and internal database searching.</li>
    <li>Advertising in Premium Mediums.</li>
    <li>Skills Assessment.</li>
    <li>Headhunting.</li>
    <li>Reference Checking.</li>
    </ul>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>

    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="tabContent" id="resources">

    <h1>Resources</h1>

    <div>

    <p>We use lots of resources like monster, totaljobs, gumtree, etc.</p>


    </div>
    </div>



    <div class="tabContent" id="computers">

    <h1>Computers</h1>

        <p>Lots of computers.</p>
        <div>

    <div id="DivPhotoGalleryFX"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var flashvars = {};
     var params = {};
     params.base = "";
     params.scale = "noscale";
     params.salign = "tl";
     params.wmode = "transparent";
     params.allowFullScreen = "true";
     params.allowScriptAccess = "always";
     swfobject.embedSWF("PhotoGalleryFX.swf", "DivPhotoGalleryFX", "935", "300", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params);


    </script>


    </div>


    </div>




    </body>

    <div id="table">

    <center>

    </div>

    <script>

    tabLinks[services].onclick = display: block;

    </script>
```

Comment: I actually want the table to appear at the bottom below the tab content,  but only when the the second tab is clicked.  The way it is right now the table appears inside of the second tab.  @Venu Gopal - The reason it is out of the body tag is because I want it to appear at the bottom of the second tab - outside of the tab itself when it is clicked.  Not inside the silver borders.